# Why is `?something` invalid?

Tags: ruby, local-variables

`?.` is a string literal:

```
?. #=> "."
```

However, I failed to declare a variable with a name like that:

```
?some_var = 100 #=> Error
```

How is`?something` invalid when `?.` is valid?

Comment: @Arup It is not a duplicate.

Comment: @sawa Ok.. I thought so .. :)

Answer (score 2):

`?` cannot describe any string literal; it is valid only for a single character.

Even if `?something` were a valid string literal (counter to fact),

```
?something = ...
```

will be assignment to a string, which does not make sense. You cannot assign a value to a string.

Answer (score 1):

`?a` is the same as `"a"`. So it is a value, which belongs on the right hand side of an assignment, not the left hand side. It is not a variable name.

The Syntax exists as a relic from Ruby <=1.9, where it was equivalent to `"a".bytes[0]` and `?d` could be used to shave off one character of code golf. I haven't seen any legitimate use otherwise.

Comment: There was a legitimate use during the transition period from 1.8 to 1.9, because it always returned the same thing that indexing string would return. So, on 1.8 `'Hello'[0] == 72` and `?H == 72` and on 1.9 `'Hello'[0] == 'H'` and `?H == 'H'`, so that it in both cases it is *always* true that `'Hello'[0] == ?H` no matter whether you are on 1.8 or 1.9.